# React Lifting State: Updating state in the child using setState function from parent

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, setstate

I've been working on variations of this problem for a while now. Basically, I have a child component that can update existing data. It updates data with no problems and the parent re-renders accordingly. The child component doesn't re-render though. So, on advice given on this site, I've tried lifting the state. I'm passing down props down to the two child components I'm running. My problem is the "EditStudent" component. I can't seem to destructure/get the "setStudent" function that's being passed down from the parent component so I'm getting a "setStudent is not a function error" no matter how I try to call this function. Any advice is greatly appreciated as it's been driving me slowly insane on how to figure this out.

Here's the code I've been working with so far.
Parent component "StudentList"

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useQuery } from "@apollo/client";
import { getStudents } from "../queries";
import StudentDetails from "./StudentDetails";
import DeleteStudent from "./DeleteStudent";
import EditStudent from "./EditStudent";


const StudentList = () => {
  const [selectedStudent, setSelectedStudent] = useState("");
  
  const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(getStudents);
  if (loading) return <p>Loading...</p>;
  if (error) return <p>Error!</p>;

  const handleClick = (student)=> {
    //console.log(student)
  
    setSelectedStudent(student);
  };
let filteredStudents = [];

//console.log(data.students)

for(let i = 0; i < data.students.length; i++){
  //console.log(data.students[i].class.name)
  if(data.students[i].class.name === "1FE1"){
    //console.log(data.students[i].name)
    filteredStudents.push(data.students[i])
  }
  
}

console.log(selectedStudent.id);
  
  return (
    
    <div>
      <ul id="student-list">
        {data.students.map((student) => (
          <li key={student.id} onClick={(e) => handleClick(student)}>{student.name}</li>
        ))}
        
      </ul>
        {
          selectedStudent ? <div>
            <StudentDetails student={selectedStudent} setStudent={setSelectedStudent}/>
           </div>
          : <p>No Student Selected</p>
          
        }
      
    </div>
  );
};

export default StudentList;
```

This is "StudentDetails" - a component receiving the "studentDetails" prop and also has two other components nested inside - "DeleteStudent" and "EditStudent"

```
import React from "react";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { getStudentQuery } from "../queries";
import { useQuery } from "@apollo/client";
import DeleteStudent from "./DeleteStudent"
import EditStudent from "./EditStudent";


const StudentDetails = ( selectedStudent )=> {
    const {setStudent} = selectedStudent;
    console.log(selectedStudent)

    //const [astudent, setStudent] = useState(props)
    
    return (
        <div id="student-details" >
            <h2>Name: {selectedStudent.student.name}</h2>
            <h3>Age: {selectedStudent.student.age}</h3>
            <h3>Class: {selectedStudent.student.class.name}</h3>
            <h3>Test 1 Score: {selectedStudent.student.test1}</h3>
            <EditStudent student={selectedStudent} setstudent={setStudent}/>
            <DeleteStudent student={selectedStudent} setter={setStudent} />
        </div>
        
    )
    
}

export default StudentDetails;
```

Finally, here is the "EditStudent" component which is causing me so many problems (can't get the setStudent function from the parent to change the state)

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useMutation } from "@apollo/react-hooks";
//import { getStudents } from "../queries";
import StudentDetails from "./StudentDetails";
import { editStudentMutation, getStudentQuery, getStudents } from "../queries/index";


const EditStudent = ( setStudent ) => {
    const { setStudent } = selectedStudent;
    console.log(props)
    const [name, setName] = useState(); 
    const [age, setAge] = useState();
    const [test, setTest] = useState();
    const [editStudent] = useMutation(editStudentMutation);

    
    return (
    
        <form id="edit-student" 
            onSubmit={(e) => {
                e.preventDefault();
                editStudent({
                variables: {
                    id: selectedStudent.student.student.id,
                    name: name,
                    age: age,
                    test1: test
                },
                refetchQueries: [{ query: getStudents}]
                })
                const aStudent = e.target.value;
                setStudent(aStudent);
            }}>
            
            <div className="field" onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}>
                <label>Student Name:</label>
                <input type="text"
                 value={name}/>
            </div>
            <div className="field" onChange={(e) => setAge(e.target.value)}>
                <label>Age:</label>
                <input type="text"
                 value={age}/>
            </div>
            <div className="field" onChange={(e) => setTest(e.target.value)}>
                <label>Test One:</label>
                <input type="text"
                 value={test}/>
            </div>
    <button type="submit" >submit</button>
        </form>
    )
}

export default EditStudent;
```

Comment: Please log the method in your child component, I belive you are accessing it directly but it's exist in the props object

console.log(props.setStudent)

Answer (score 1):

Your method named in your props `setstudent` "check left side of passed props"

```
<EditStudent student={selectedStudent} setstudent={setStudent}/>
```

and please access it like the following

```
const EditStudent = ( {setstudent} ) => {}

// or
const EditStudent = ( props ) => {

 props.setstudent()
}
```

And these lines of code don't seem correct, from where you get this selectedStudent? your props named `setStudent` then you are accessing it to get the method `setStudent`

```
const EditStudent = ( setStudent ) => {
    const { setStudent } = selectedStudent;
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm trying this out, but the problem is, if I destructure const EditStudent = ({setStudent}) I can't define the id anymore. I've tried EditStudent = ({setStudent, selectedStudent}) but it still gives me an undefined error.

Comment: You sould access it like this
`const EditStudent = ( {setstudent, student} ) => {}` and then console.log them

Comment: What is on the left side is what will be in your props

Comment: Please be aware of the method signature it's `setstudent` and not `setStudent` the `S` in a student is the lower case so your props are `student`   `setstudent` and not `setStudent, selectedStudent`

Comment: Thanks! I think I'm getting close thanks to your help. I've corrected the props as you mentioned (such a simple mistake!) but I'm still having a problem with the error "setstudent is not a function." I think it's that last line in the event handler. I'm not exactly sure what to pass to the handler.

Comment: Pass what you would expect in your parent `state` e.g: `student name or Id etc`, please do some console.log in your parent-child components, your issue now need some investigation and reading your code